# Restrictions on number using typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to define a type/interface (don't care which for the purpose of this exercise) that uses generics that has two properties:

```
interface Response<T> {
  status: number;
  data: T | undefined;
}
```

The restriction I want to capture is that when status !== 200, data must be undefined. When status === 200, data must be T. This way, I don't always have to check to see if response.data is not undefined after I check to make sure response.status is 200:

```
if (response.status === 200 && response.data) {
  // Wouldn't it be nice it TS just knew that response.data is
  // not undefined without having to check it explicitly?
}
```

So far, I have this:

```
interface IOkResponse<T> {
  status: 200;
  data: T;
}

interface IErrorResponse {
  status: number;
  data: undefined;
}

type Response<T> = IOkResponse<T> | IErrorResponse;
```

Of course, since IErrorResponse does not restrict status to numbers that are not 200, this doesn't work. How would I go about adding that restriction?

Comment: Not ideal, but you could list *every other* status you support. There's only about ~60 so not the end of the world.

Comment: If there isn't a better way, that's what I intend on doing :)

Comment: TypeScript doesn't support negated types (it was [worked on](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) for a while and eventually abandoned), so there's no way to say "`number & not 200`".  If your type were the *string* `"200"` one could programmatically generate all three digit string literals from `"100"` to `"599"` and exclude `"200"` in TS4.1, but if you want a numeric literal it would probably be best to just enumerate the valid codes in a manual union.  If you're interested in the string literal version let me know.

Comment: @jcalz Btw, how can I reach you?. I wrote you an email, but I'm not sure you read it

Comment: @captain-yossarian I received the email but I didn't know it was from you... I don't know if I can commit to interacting much with your blog but I don't mind you referencing my answers or mentioning me; it's all good 

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, a lot!!!

Comment: @jcalz Given the shape of my code, I think it'll be simpler for me to just use an enum that lists out status codes I care for and use Exclude on the enum. But if you have a pointer on how to programmatically generate string literals, I'd love to learn for future projects!

Comment: @KMehta see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/zwObpW) for some more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @jcalz, there is no hacky way to do it.
One thing you cand do is typeguards. It will provide to your code type safety but you should pay for it - function overhead.

```js
interface IOkResponse<T> {
  status: 200;
  data: T;
}

interface IErrorResponse {
  status: number;
  data: undefined
}

type Result<T> = IOkResponse<T> | IErrorResponse;

const isOK = <T,>(arg: Result<T>): arg is IOkResponse<T> => arg.status === 200

const foo = <T,>(arg: Result<T>) => {
  if (isOK(arg)) {
    const y = arg //  IOkResponse<T> 
  } else {
    const z = arg // IErrorResponse;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Response<T> {
    status: number = null;
    get data(): T {
        return this.status === 200 && this.data || undefined;
    }
}
```

How about trying something like this?, data will be undefined if the status === 200

Answer (score 0):

While @captain-yossarin has a functional solution that's more generic in nature (which is why I formally accepted that as the answer), here's the solution I went with...

```
export enum StatusCode {
  OK = 200,
  NoContent = 204,
  NotModified = 304,
  BadRequest = 400,
  Unauthorized = 401,
  // Other status codes that the client cares about go here
}

interface IOkResponse<T> {
  statusCode: StatusCode.OK;
  data: T;
}

interface IErrorResponse {
  statusCode: Exclude<StatusCode, StatusCode.OK>;
  data: undefined;
}

export type ApiResponse<T> = IOkResponse<T> | IErrorResponse;
```

This function, which is responsible for creating an instance of my `ApiResponse<T>` object works fine because TypeScript will implicitly cast `number` to `StatusCode`.

```
async function parseResponse<T>(response: Response): Promise<ApiResponse<T>> {
  const text = await response.text();
  const statusCode = response.status;
  if (statusCode === StatusCode.OK) {
    const data = JSON.parse(text) as T;
    return { statusCode, data };
  }
  return { statusCode, data: undefined };
}
```

Now, I can use my `ApiResponse<T>` object without unnecessary undefined checks when `statusCode === 200`.

```
const ar1: ApiResponse<Test> = { statusCode: 200, data: { value: 5 } };
if (ar1.statusCode === StatusCode.OK) {
  console.log(ar1.data.value);
}
```